# trying to get the selected items string out of a materialbetterSpinner but it shows can't resolve symbol getSelectedItem();(Which is for spinner)

Tags: android, android-spinner

```
MaterialBetterSpinner university;

university = (MaterialBetterSpinner) findViewById(R.id.university);
```

and my select code is---

```
university.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                String seluniversity = (String) university.getSelectedItem();
```

here is the issue

Comment: Where's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

To get the selected item.

You can follow this page for more https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html